# How to setup the Output and Intermeidate directory in visual studio to be dependent on current git branch?

Tags: git, visual-studio, compilation, git-branch

I'm looking for a solution, to avoid lot of recompiling when moving from branch to branch in git.
Using different folders for different branches is solution, but It just created chaos in my workflow.

The best solution I can think of would be to pass the git branch as the options $ variable used in project settings, so I could set the "Output directory" to something like

```
..\bin\$(branch)\$(Configuration)$(Platform)\
```

Similar with intermediate directory.

Is something like this possible to configure?

Edit:
The problem is, that even when the output/intermediate directory is different per branch (or moved from archive when changing branches), the precompiled headers are always recompiled anyway, so the project is recompiled as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution 1

I think OP's way to use `$(branch)` is cool. But there's no way to create a user macro with the dynamic value of the branch name in `Visual Studio`. And it's either impossible for `Visual Studio` to reload environment variables if we add it in the `pre-build` event after the VS starts, unless it's restarted. It seems the most straightforward way is just to do it in `post-checkout` hook in `git` repository as `@ConfusedSushi` mentioned.

I just tested the solution and it worked well. The details are as follows.

Create git hook `post-checkout` (that the file name is just `post-checkout`, and put it into `GIT_DIR/.git/hooks`. It will call a batch file `set-branch.bat`.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$3" -eq "1" ]; then
    cmd.exe /c "`pwd`/.git/hooks/set-branch.bat" 
fi
```

The batch file `set-branch.bat` is as follows. And also put it into `GIT_DIR/.git/hooks`.

```
@echo off

for /f %%i in ('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD') do setx branch %%i
```

And then set the `Output directory` as OP did:

```
..\bin\$(branch)\$(Configuration)$(Platform)\
```

Now, every time when the branch is changed via `git check`, an environment variable `branch` will be set. And you **need to restart `Visual Studio` to get the environment variable value**. It just works as you need.

### Solution 2

Due to OP's comment, another solution is to let the visual studio use the same folder, but move the Output/intermediate directories in the post-checkout hook.

Just create a git hook `post-checkout` with following scripts. And **replace my test folder below `Test/Test/Debug` with your own real folder. And it can be absolute directory or related to git repository.** The build folder will be added `branch name` as suffix if it's not current branch.

```
#!/bin/bash

build_folder=Test/Test/Debug
if [ "$3" -eq "1" ]; then
    oldref=$(git reflog | awk 'NR==1{ print $6; exit }')
    newref=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

    if [ "$oldref" != "$newref" ]; then
        if [ -d "$build_folder-$oldref" ]; then
            rm -rf "$build_folder-$oldref"
            echo "Deleted $build_folder-$oldref"
        fi

        if [ -d "$build_folder" ]; then
            mv "$build_folder" "$build_folder-$oldref"
            echo "Moved $build_folder to $build_folder-$oldref"
        fi

        if [ -d "$build_folder-$newref" ]; then
            mv "$build_folder-$newref" "$build_folder"
            echo "Moved $build_folder-$newref to $build_folder"
        fi
    fi
fi
```

**[Updated]** For the edited question, since the precompiled headers always change when switching branches, the projects are always recompiled. There's actually a solution, but a bit **dangerous**.

`VS` detects the `modified time` of a source file to decide whether it needs to be recompiled. So what we can do is **to change the `modified time` to cheat `VS`**. We can do it with the command `touch`.

But it's hard to decide which time is suitable. To make it practical, we can choose a file that doesn't change by switching branches, and also relatively stable, and set the `modified time` of the precompiled headers the same as the chosen file. We can also do it in the `post-checkout` hook.

```
touch -r some_stable_chosen_file precompiled_header
```

**But we should remember it's not safe, because it may also ignore the real changes to the precompiled headers. We have to manually deal with it.**

Comment: Ok, and is it possible to restart the visual studio automatically? If it needs to be restarted? Maybe it would be better to let the visual studio use the same folder, but move the Output/intermediate directories in the pre/post-checkout branch?

Comment: I think it's better not to restart vs in script, for you may have several solutions opened, and the script may have to close them all and restart. But what you need is only to restart the one related with branch switching. The second question is considerable. I'll try it later and update the answer if it's practicable.

Comment: @kovarex Have updated the answer. Any problem please let me know.

Comment: The problem is, that even when I'm moving the files, the Precompiled header (Compile.hpp) for the project is recompiled, so the whole project is recompiled again. I have no idea what could be the cause. I tried to move the ipch folder as well, but it didn't help.

Comment: @kovarex It works in my test. Are your precompiled headers or project files the same among different branches? If they are different, `git checkout` will reload these files. And `VS` will detect these changes, and think that they should be recompiled.

Comment: Yes, these branches have different header files included in precompiled headers, but I just started all this to avoid the recompilation when the headers are different. I checked that the project files are the same.

Comment: It's rather another story. I posted a solution in my answer ([updated] part), though it's not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You could setup a post-checkout hook in git.  This hook could run a batch file which is determining the current branch and passing this to an environment variable.  You should use [SETX](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) to set the environment variable to permanently set it.  In MsBuild-Files you can use environment variables.  So your suggested project setting should work then.  Of course you also can implement your hook in your favorite language instead using a batch file.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution based on Landys answer I actually use to avoid the need to restart visual studio to reload new value of the enviromental variable.

The script just uses the directory branches/<branch> for the  intermediate/output directories of the branches. In the post-checkout hook, the previous directories are moved to the archive, and the needed ones are moved to their place.

```
#!/bin/bash

prevHEAD=$1                                                                      
newHEAD=$2                                                                       
checkoutType=$3                                                                  

if [ $checkoutType -ne 1 ] ; then exit ; fi

prevBranch=`git name-rev --name-only $prevHEAD`
newBranch=`git name-rev --name-only $newHEAD`

targetDir=vs-2013-files/branches/$prevBranch
mkdir -p $targetDir
mv vs-2013-files/*Win32 vs-2013-files/*Win32Lib vs-2013-files/*x64 vs-2013-files/*x64Lib $targetDir 2>/dev/null
mv bin $targetDir 2>/dev/null

sourceDir=vs-2013-files/branches/$newBranch
mv $sourceDir/*Win32 $sourceDir/*Win32Lib $sourceDir/*x64 $sourceDir/*x64Lib vs-2013-files    2>/dev/null
mv $sourceDir/bin . 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: There's a problem for `git name-rev --name-only $prevHEAD`. If two branches such as `dev1` and `dev2` point to the same commit object, the script will only get one branch name like `dev1` even when it checks out to other branch from `dev2`. You can refer to my answer.